# How to fetch data from a column of a gridview and perform arithmetic operations on the column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am working on a Cart project, and using Visual Studio 2010 with SQL server express. I am using a Gridview to display data from my cart table in my database. I have a product table in my database , and I insert products from product table to  the cart table . after that i display the cart in the gridview. the problem I am facing is i cannot use the Price column from my gridview to add the prices of the items in the cart to display the total price of the order. how can i do that?
my asp gridview source code is as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="4" CssClass="table table-condensed" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    DataKeyNames="serial_no" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="serial_no" InsertVisible="False" 
                            SortExpression="serial_no">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("serial_no") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("serial_no") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
                            SortExpression="Name" ControlStyle-CssClass="cart_menu" >
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
                            SortExpression="Quantity" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" 
                            SortExpression="Price" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="serial_no">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("serial_no") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                                    onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>


                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FF7800" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="cart_menu" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF7800" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="cart_menu" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

my sqldatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cs %>" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cs.ProviderName %>" 

                    SelectCommand="SELECT cartdemo.serial_no, Product.Name, Product.P_Image, Product.Price, cartdemo.Quantity FROM cartdemo INNER JOIN Product ON cartdemo.ProductID = Product.ProductID WHERE (cartdemo.CID = @cid)" 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM cartdemo WHERE (serial_no = @sl_no)">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="sl_no" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="cid" SessionField="ssid" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my c# code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class cart2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow grd = e.Row;
        switch (grd.RowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)grd.FindControl("Button1");
                    if (btn != null)
                    {
                        Label lbl_pid = (Label)grd.FindControl("Label1");
                        btn.CommandArgument = lbl_pid.Text;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

        calTotal(4);

    }
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        string id = btn.CommandArgument;
        SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters[0].DefaultValue = id;
        SqlDataSource1.Delete();
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    public void calTotal(int curCol)
    {
        decimal valueColumn = 0;
        //try
        //{
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            valueColumn = valueColumn + Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[curCol].Text);
        }
        //}
        //catch(Exception r)
        //{
        //}

        Label3.Text = "Rs." + valueColumn.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, what you are wanting to know about is the SQL function "SUM". You can find more information about sum [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php). The short version is that SUM returns the total for a column of NUMERIC data. The basic syntax looks something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(myColumn)
FROM myTable;
/* Assume myColumn contains {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} */
/* The output of this SELECT statement would be {15} */
```

Comment: no im actually trying to use this code 

    public void calTotal(int curCol)
    {
        decimal valueColumn = 0;
        //try
        //{
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            valueColumn = valueColumn + Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[curCol].Text);
        }
        //}
        //catch(Exception r)
        //{
        //}


        Label3.Text = "Rs." + valueColumn.ToString();
    }

Comment: i want to fetch data from a column of the gridview and store it in a label.

Comment: when i run my code there is a formatexception error thrown

Comment: Hmm, do you think you post that code as an edit to your original post so I can see it with the correct formatting? Because right now, there are too many random comments to piece together what is and is not commented out

Comment: I believe you are missing your end tags for ///
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" /// 
and ///  <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" /// However, I am not incredibly familiar with ASP.NET, and I am mostly basing this off of your other code and experience with XML

Comment: haha it was a mistake on my part. i had given the wrong index in row.Cells[4].Text , i should have used 3 instead of 4! Thanks for taking out ur time anyway , Jake :)

Comment: Oh well, sorry I was not of much help, but at least we got the problem solved. Good luck on the remainder of the project :)